# How can I center content on mobile with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I need to center elements when i visit from mobile. On desktop is looking ok.

Desktop:
[image]

Mobile:

[image]

Desired mobile:

[image]

I use Bootstrap 5.3.0. I tried with `row` and `col` but the i don't get the desktop result as i want.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-sm-nowrap mb-0">
  <div class="text-center">
    <!--begin::Image-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-shrink-0 bg-light rounded w-100px h-100px w-lg-150px h-lg-150px me-7 mb-4 border border-secondary">
      <img class="mw-50px mw-lg-75px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="image">
    </div>
    <!--end::Image-->
  </div>
  <!--begin::Wrapper-->
  <div class="flex-grow-1">
    <!--begin::Head-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start flex-wrap mb-2">
      <!--begin::Details-->
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <!--begin::Status-->
        <div class="align-items-center mb-1">
          <a class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3" href="#">Title Subject</a>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">-</span>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">Location</span>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">-</span>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">title subject2</span>
          <span class="badge badge-info me-auto">Badge</span>
        </div>
        <!--end::Status-->
        <!--begin::Description-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap fw-semibold">
          <span class="me-2 fs-5 text-white-400">Status</span>
          <span class="mb-0 fs-5 text-white-400">
                        <em>unknown yet</em>
                    </span>
        </div>
        <!--end::Description-->
        <!--begin::User id-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap fw-semibold mb-0 fs-5 text-gray-400 d-none" id="legal_case_id">20</div>
        <!--end::User id-->
      </div>
      <!--end::Details-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Head-->
    <!--begin::Info-->
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start">
      <!--begin::Stats-->
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
        <!--begin::Stat-->
        <div class="border border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded min-w-125px py-3 px-4 me-6 mb-3">
          <!--begin::Number-->
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="fs-4 fw-bold">27 Jun, 2023</div>
          </div>
          <!--end::Number-->
          <!--begin::Label-->
          <div class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-gray-400">event from mob</div>
          <!--end::Label-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Stat-->
        <!--begin::Stat-->
        <div class="border border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded min-w-125px py-3 px-4 me-6 mb-3">
          <!--begin::Number-->
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="fs-4 fw-bold counted" data-kt-countup="true" data-kt-countup-value="0" data-kt-initialized="1">0</div>
          </div>
          <!--end::Number-->
          <!--begin::Label-->
          <div class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-gray-400">Files</div>
          <!--end::Label-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Stat-->
      </div>
      <!--end::Stats-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Info-->
  </div>
  <!--end::Wrapper-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following:

- `mx-auto` to center the image
- `text-sm-start text-center` to center the *Title Subject - Location - title subject2* on mobile
- `me-sm-auto mx-auto d-sm-inline d-table` to center the badge on mobile
- `justify-content-sm-start justify-content-center` to center the status on mobile
- use Bootstrap grid system for the bottom two cards

See the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-sm-nowrap mb-0">
  <div class="text-center mx-auto">
    <!--begin::Image-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-shrink-0 bg-light rounded w-100px h-100px w-lg-150px h-lg-150px me-7 mb-4 border border-secondary">
      <img class="mw-50px mw-lg-75px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="image">
    </div>
    <!--end::Image-->
  </div>
  <!--begin::Wrapper-->
  <div class="flex-grow-1">
    <!--begin::Head-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start flex-wrap mb-2">
      <!--begin::Details-->
      <div class="d-flex flex-column text-sm-start text-center">
        <!--begin::Status-->
        <div class="align-items-center mb-1">
          <a class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3" href="#">Title Subject</a>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">-</span>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">Location</span>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">-</span>
          <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">title subject2</span>
          <span class="badge text-bg-primary badge-info me-sm-auto mx-auto d-sm-inline d-table">Badge</span>
        </div>
        <!--end::Status-->
        <!--begin::Description-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap fw-semibold justify-content-sm-start justify-content-center">
          <span class="me-2 fs-5 text-white-400">Status</span>
          <span class="mb-0 fs-5 text-white-400">
            <em>unknown yet</em>
          </span>
        </div>
        <!--end::Description-->
        <!--begin::User id-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap fw-semibold mb-0 fs-5 text-gray-400 d-none" id="legal_case_id">20</div>
        <!--end::User id-->
      </div>
      <!--end::Details-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Head-->
    <!--begin::Info-->
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start">
      <!--begin::Stats-->
      <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap w-100">
        <!--begin::Stat-->
        <div class="col-sm-auto col-6">
          <div class="border border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded min-w-125px py-3 px-4 me-6 mb-3">
            <!--begin::Number-->
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="fs-4 fw-bold">27 Jun, 2023</div>
            </div>
            <!--end::Number-->
            <!--begin::Label-->
            <div class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-gray-400">event from mob</div>
            <!--end::Label-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end::Stat-->
        <!--begin::Stat-->
        <div class="col-sm-auto col-6">
          <div class="border border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded min-w-125px py-3 px-4 me-6 mb-3">
            <!--begin::Number-->
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="fs-4 fw-bold counted" data-kt-countup="true" data-kt-countup-value="0" data-kt-initialized="1">0</div>
            </div>
            <!--end::Number-->
            <!--begin::Label-->
            <div class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-gray-400">Files</div>
            <!--end::Label-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end::Stat-->
      </div>
      <!--end::Stats-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Info-->
  </div>
  <!--end::Wrapper-->
</div>
```

Comment: works like a charm, ty ... you usually put mobile then desktop parameters or other way around ?

Comment: @Sofnam No. I set the class that affects desktop first (i.e., `text-sm-start`) and then the class that affects mobile (i.e., `text-center`), but this is just a personal preference. For example, you can do `text-sm-start text-center` or `text-center text-sm-start`. If you chose the "mobile-first" approach, then use `text-center text-sm-start`. What's more important is that you're consistent. Meaning, if you chose `text-sm-start text-center`, then do it this way on the whole page and all pages of your project.

Comment: your approach is desktop-mobile, first `*-sm-*` then normal, what if you have big desktop, desktop, tablet, phone, how you would do? `text-lg-start text-sm-start text-xs-start text-center` i guess

Comment: @Sofnam Yes, exactly. But now that you're starting to learn Bootstrap, I strongly suggest you get used to the "mobile-first" approach. So, I suggest you do `text-center text-sm-start`. In case you want to have a different layout for more breakpoints, do `text-center text-sm-start text-md-start text-lg-start text-xl-start text-xxl-start`. But, this is unnecessary! Why? Because `text-center text-sm-start text-md-start text-lg-start text-xl-start text-xxl-start` will result in the same output as `text-center text-sm-start`. It's redundant code. Also, `*-xs-*` doesn't exist!

Comment: i understand what you say, but why you tell me to use "mobile-first" instead of "bigger to lower" instead?

Comment: Read [Mobile First Design: What it is and How to Implement it](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-implement-mobile-first-design). You'll understand why I recommend the "mobile-first" approach.

Answer (score 3):

You'd set [justification](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content) to center for mobile (default), then override it for larger breakpoints, as `justify-content-center justify-content-md-start`.

Your horizontal list needs refactoring, too. It's not quite centered. It needs tweaking or refactoring to use flex features rather than margins.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-sm-nowrap mb-0 justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-shrink-0 bg-light rounded w-100px h-100px w-lg-150px h-lg-150px me-7 mb-4 border border-secondary">
    <img class="mw-50px mw-lg-75px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-grow-1">
  <div class="d-flex  justify-content-center justify-content-md-start justify-content-md-between align-items-start flex-wrap mb-2">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="align-items-center mb-1">
        <a class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3" href="#">Title Subject</a>
        <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">-</span>
        <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">Location</span>
        <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">-</span>
        <span class="text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fs-2 fw-bold me-3">title subject2</span>
        <span class="badge badge-info me-auto">Badge</span>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap fw-semibold justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
        <span class="me-2 fs-5 text-white-400">Status</span>
        <span class="mb-0 fs-5 text-white-400">
            <em>unknown yet</em>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap fw-semibold mb-0 fs-5 text-gray-400 d-none" id="legal_case_id">20</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="border border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded min-w-125px py-3 px-4 me-6 mb-3">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="fs-4 fw-bold">27 Jun, 2023</div>
        </div>

        <div class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-gray-400">event from mob</div>
      </div>

      <div class="border border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded min-w-125px py-3 px-4 me-6 mb-3">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="fs-4 fw-bold counted" data-kt-countup="true" data-kt-countup-value="0" data-kt-initialized="1">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-gray-400">Files</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does not work as expected
https://ibb.co/mDy3rvR

All you sent it is contained in a `card-body` : https://justpaste.it/bcylj ... might affect

badge is not on centered on single row

on desktop works as expected

Comment: You're moving the goalposts. Not my problem. Update the question to accurately represent your case.